# Import data tier application using bacpac

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I had Export my Database backup from Azure DB in .bacpac form successfully, but when I'am going to import that .bacpac it will throw an error.

[image: This is the error that I facing while import .bacpac]

Comment: The error is pretty simple: "Database master keys without password are not supported in this version of SQL Server". The executed script: `CREATE MASTER KEY`.

Comment: Is this the statement you asking for?

CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'key';  
GO

Answer (score 1):

You probably had blob auditing enabled on your Azure SQL, right?

Please have a look at this article: [Exported database from Azure SQL failed to be imported to Azure SQL or to local SQL Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/03/30/exported-database-from-azure-sql-failed-to-be-imported-to-azure-sql-or-to-local-sql-server/)

***Taken from that article:***

**The cause:**
This caused by a different behavior between Azure SQL DB and Local SQL Server installation

a master key without password is an Azure SQL DB only feature, while local SQL Server installation must have password encryption for master key.

**Resolution:**

*Option 1*
to mitigate import to Azure SQL DB use the import from the Azure portal.

to mitigate import to local SQL Server installation you can alter the existing master key and add password encryption to it.

this should be done before you export the database

`ALTER MASTER KEY ADD ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<PasswordHere>';`

*Option 2*
for short term mitigation we provide you PowerShell script that do the following:

remove the master key object from the bacpac
remove the credential object from the bacpac

after running this PS script on the bacpac you will have new bacpac file with "patched" suffix.

Answer (score 1):

Before exporting your database as bacpac you need to do the following steps:

1. Disable Database Auditing if you have it enabled.
2. Drop the database master key with DROP MASTER KEY command.

After that export your database again and import it on your local SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully resolve this issue, first I execute CREATE MASTER KEY script in azure db instance, then export that Database. And then import that database to local SQL server.